# A method for ordering mixed dates in search result loop (theory only, no actual code)

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, filters, actions, meta-query

**My issue**

Hello,
some time ago:

- I had the regular `post` and the custom `evento` post types;
- the `evento` post type had a `ev_data_out` custom field;
- the search result loop had to return a list of posts from both the post types (if relevant for the search), ordered by date;
- for `post` the considered field when ordering had to be the regular `post_date`, while for `evento` it had to be `ev_data_out`.

An example to clarify better.
These posts' dates:

```
PT "post"                PT "evento"
-----------------------  -------------------------
post_date = 2019-10-10   ev_data_out = 2020-11-10
post_date = 2017-03-12   ev_data_out = 2018-12-01
```

had to return a list ordered this way:

```
Results
--------------
2020-11-10
2019-10-10
2018-12-01
2017-03-12
```

**My solution**

Since my knowledge of Wp Query was (and is) still basic but I needed a fast implementation, I came out with this:

1. I hooked a function to `post_save` telling it to `update_post_meta` a post meta called `order_date` for each post type, with `post_date`'s value if `post` and `ev_data_out`'s value if `evento`;
2. I filtered `pre_get_posts` with a function that conditioned to `if (is_search && !is_admin())` and setting `$query -> set('meta_key', 'order_date');` and `$query -> set('orderby', 'meta_value');`

**My question**

So far I never had to retouch this stuff for it seems to work perfectly.

My question is, rather, if there is a method *inherently* better in Wordpress terms, i.e. if -with a better knowledge of the Wp Query, and of the meta queries in particular- I could get something more efficient and less DB-consuming.

N.b. I wish to understand things and not only to copy/paste, so an answer like "yes, study Wp Query better and you'll get the same result" would be perfectly fine for me!

Thanks!